# Check if row in table is 'equal' to other row

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to check if a row exists in MySQL:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$code = $_POST['code'];
mysql_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass");
mysql_select_db("$dbname");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM files WHERE id='$code' LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo 'Exists';
} else {
    echo 'Does not exist';
}
}
?>
```

This works fine. But I need to change it a bit. I have the following fields:
`id`, `title`, `url`, `type`. When someone uses the code above ^ to check if a row exists, I need a variable to get the `url` from the same row, so I can redirect the user to there.

Do you have any idea how I can do that?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If you want to keep on going being unsafe, [check this](http://nl3.php.net/mysql_fetch_row). Otherwise, otherwise, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/777850). And please use google or show some effort on some other way next time.

Comment: @giorgio Thanks. So if I understand correctly, I can do $row[row_number]? I don't get what variable I should use instead of $row though..

Comment: OK, so I did `$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);` and then `echo 'Ja' . $row[0];`, but every lookup now returns 'Does not exist'.. and I don't see `$row[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$code = $_POST['code'];
mysql_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass");
mysql_select_db("$dbname");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE id=" . $code . " LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         echo 'Exists';
         $url = $rows['url'];
    }
 } else {
    echo 'Does not exist';
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: url in ... on line 50` Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake, try the new code, I think I fixed the issue

Comment: Nope... when it exists same error as above, when it doesn't no output or error.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you did a fetch row instead of a fetch array, so it makes sense why you would receive that error as my declared rows variable was a single row and not an array, it should work now -- Sorry about the error, the pc I am currently on does not have a php server installed locally.

Comment: Also, just FYI, mysql_* functions have been deprecated, you shouldn't use them anymore, rather use PDO and/or MySQLi, it is safer and more secure

Comment: OK, I understand :) I'm still getting an error though. When it doesn't exist I just get Does not exist, when it does I get Exists `Notice: Undefined index: url in /home/wdele/domains/hypah.org/public_html/code.php on line 50`.. And thanks for the advice.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your column name is url? That should be the only thin wrong in the above code t=is the URL column name

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't think you understand what I am trying to do. Let's say: the user looks up value `1` via the form. PHP checks if `1` exists in the row `2`. If it does, it outputs value `3` from the form.

Comment: So the URL is not coming from a database, it is coming from a form?

Comment: It's coming from a database: on the `create.php` a user can fill in a form with the code (ID) and URL, which is sent to the database and stored there. On the `code.php` the user should be able to enter a code and PHP should automatically look up what code is assigned to it. That's what I'm asking for :)

Comment: Ok, I noticed a few errors in your select statement which is why it did not work, I have fixed them (see the code above) you can alter your select statement to return only the url aswell, but returning all will allow you to get other rows if you ever need

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. I think you don't show any effort to find the solution by yourself.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$code = $_POST['code'];
mysql_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass");
mysql_select_db("$dbname");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM files WHERE id='$code' LIMIT 1");
if ($result) {
  $url = mysql_fetch_row($resultado);
} else {
   echo 'Does not exist';
}
}
```

Comment: No, because I didn't have any clue how to :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE userid ='$userid'";
$result1 =mysql_query($sql_query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result1)>0){
while($post = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
$url = $post['url'];    

    }
    }
?>
```

If mysql_num_rows($result1)>0 it means row is existed fir the given user id